# Angular2 AoT - module.id is not defined while setting module.id in component

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I am facing a challenge with Angular2 AoT and any help will be a big one for me since I am stuck.

I have a simple hello world app which has main.js, home.module.ts, home.component.ts, home.component.html and home.service.ts. This code works well using Angular2 without AoT.

After I perform AoT and Rollup precisely as per angular.io steps in cookbook, i am getting error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined" and I have no clue why this is happening.

My Home.Component.ts is marked like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'rf-home',
    moduleId: module.id,   // i m setting this module.id so that I can use relative template paths in my code. Helps in Dev env.
    templateUrl: 'Home.component.html',
    providers: [HomeService]
})
```

Someone out there, please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update: 22 October 2016

As of Angular 2.1 the AOT section of the docs (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) there is a much simpler method.

```
<script>window.module = 'aot';</script>
```

This line goes in the index.html file for the aot build.

## tl;dr

The fix that I am using is to add a custom provider that checks if the module object is available in the browser and adds it into the global scope if it is not found.

1. Create the following class: rollup-module.provider.ts

   ```
   export function RollupModuleProvider(params: any) {
       return function (target: any) {
           // Setup the 'module' variable globally. The rollup javascript has its own module system, but there is still a
           // reference to the Commonjs module.id in the code, so setup a module object to allow that code to execute
           // without throwing an exception
           try {
               // In dev mode with commonjs the following line will execute without a problem
               // In AoT mode with rollup the following line will trigger an exception that will be
               // caught and handled to allow the AoT build to run without issue
               let testIfRunningWithCommonJSandModuleIsAvailable = module.id;
           } catch (e) {
               // Declare Module for rollup based production builds.
               // When running dev builds CommonJS automatically provides the module definition
               console.log("Defining Module");
               var globalScope: any;
               if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
                   globalScope = global;
               }
               else {
                   globalScope = window;
               }
               globalScope.module = "test";
               try {
                   let moduleShouldBeAvailable = module;
               }
               catch (e) {
                   // Our attempt to register module failed so we are not in an unrecoverable error state.
                   console.error("Module not defined");
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. In your app.component.ts add the following snippet. Note that app.component.ts should be the class that is in the "bootstrap" declaration in the app.module.ts file.

   ```
   import {RollupModuleProvider} from "./rollup-module.provider";

   @RollupModuleProvider({})
   ```

## Details

For completeness this is the full app.component.ts below. Note I inline the template in this component to further simplify the build. For other components in the application 'template' can be used to inline the html or 'templateUrl' can be used to put the html in a separate file. For all the components besides the main app.component.ts this choice can be based on personal/project preference.

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    import './rxjs-operators';
    import {ModalService} from "./shared/modal.service";
    import {RollupModuleProvider} from "./rollup-module.provider";

    @RollupModuleProvider({})
    @Component({
        selector: 'myapp',
        /* For only the top level component inline the template which simplifies the build process. By in-lining the
         * template we don't need to setup the "module: module.id" on the Component decorator. We use the RollupModuleProvider
         * to setup the module variable when running in a ngc/rollup build. In a dev build the CommonJs module system is used
         * so module.id is available. In a ngc/rollup build the module does not need to be set on the component so it can be
         * set to a valid value and then is essentially ignored.
         */
        template:
            `<div [class.modalDisplayed]="modalService.isModalDisplayed()"></div>
                <nav-header></nav-header>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
            </div>`
    })

    export class AppComponent {
        constructor (public modalService: ModalService) {
        }
    }
```

This is the full app.module.ts.

```
    import {NgModule}      from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

    import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
    import { routing } from './app.routing';

    import { Logger } from './logger.service';
    import { HttpClient } from './http.client.service';
    import {WindowSize} from './window-size.service';
    import {ModalService} from "./shared/modal.service";
    import {SharedModule} from "./shared/shared.module";

    @NgModule({
        imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, routing, SharedModule],
        declarations: [AppComponent],
        providers: [ Logger, HttpClient, WindowSize, ModalService ],
        bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
    })

    export class AppModule { }
```

### Detailed explanation

As part of the solution I wanted to be able to leave the moduleId definition in the code so that I could continue running tsc and use commonjs for development. The AoT doesn't require a moduleId to function. The UncaughtReferenceError occurs in the browser with the AoT build because the browser doesn't have "module" available in the global scope (generally the JavaScript window object). In development mode commonjs sets up the module so there is no issue.

Since AoT doesn't need the moduleId the fix is to simply setup a module object within the browser when running in AoT mode. The module object doesn't have to do anything besides being defined to keep from throwing the reference error.

The code for setting up the global scope is from the angular 2 code-base, just slightly modified for this usage.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for the inputs and sorry for late reply. I've had added a dummy.

Comment: @Brian : I tried your approach and still it failed. One question. Should I add     @RollupModuleProvider({}) to all the components or in just AppComponent?

Comment: Abhijith, see the very top of my comment that I updated on Oct 22. The Angular team has updated the Angular documentation with a much simpler workaround for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix this bug:

1. Remove moduleId: module.id
2. Replace **templateUrl: 'Home.component.html'** by 
   **template:
   require('to-string!./Home.component.html.html')**

   @Component({
        selector: 'rf-home',
       template: require('to-string!./Home.component.html.html'),
       providers: [HomeService]
   })

Comment: Yeah, `moduleId` in a component decorator is an ugly hack. Note if using SystemJS, this would look like `import template from './home.component.html';` `@Component({template, providers[...],...})`

Comment: I was under the impression that you could not use the "require()" call when compiling with AOT.  Doing so will cause this error: "Calling function 'require', function calls are not supported"